# When using MVVM, is it okay to use property injection on a view model in WPF?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, wpf, mvvm

I am rather new to the concept of MVVM in C#/.NET WPF projects. The way I understand it, the view-model is supposed to lessen the amount of code-behind required to display data on a form. I try to do as much of the interaction logic as possible in the view-model, so any objects I will use get passed into the view-model via property injection. The view-model will then utilize those objects to do whatever the application is supposed to do.

The only logic I have in the view is to instantiate something based on a user selection and pass it immediately into the view-model. Additionally, I only really need to do that with a few things that don't make sense to bind (everything else uses data-binding).

What I am asking is... Is it generally okay to pass objects to the view-model? Or, does that create some kind of coupling or other problems I am not aware of?

Comment: I would start with [this CodeProject article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/100175/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained).  [This one also looks promising](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/819294/WPF-MVVM-step-by-step-Basics-to-Advance-Level).  Once you have a good grasp of MVVM in a WPF context, it should become apparent whether or not what you're trying to do is kosher.

Comment: `The view-model will then utilize those objects to do whatever the application is supposed to do` -- If that means doing anything other than UI interaction logic, it probably *is not* kosher.  Business logic belongs in the Model, not the ViewModel..

Comment: As always, thank you @RobertHarvey. I guess that statement isn't very clear, the *view-model* only obtains data from my *model*... Furthermore, this data is bound by the *view* via public properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of objects do you want to pass to your ViewModel?

My view of MVVM is that my ViewModels are my application, and the View is just a pretty user-friendly interface for interacting with the ViewModels. In an ideal world, you should be able to easily hook up a command-line interface to your ApplicationViewModel and perform the same actions.

It sounds like you have the View creating an object based on a View's SelectedItem, and trying to pass the created object to a ViewModel. That's typically not what you want.

What you should have is a ViewModel containing a SelectedItem (which is bound to the View to give the user an easy way to change it), and that ViewModel should create your object using the `ViewModel.SelectedItem` property. From there, it can pass it to another ViewModel if needed, or take some other action on it.

I have a very [simple MVVM example](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) on my blog if you're interested in understanding the pattern a bit more. Its what I typically give to WPF beginners on StackOverflow who are looking for a basic example. :)

Comment: Thank you I have seen your blog before actually, I believe I used that example to get started with MVVM.